# Callback teams Messaging Extension Adaptive Card

Tags: authentication, callback, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, user-data

I've developed a custom teams messaging extension app that correctly returns after search.
Now I've a problem that I want to pass the user data (aaid and tid or the received access token) from the message extension to my custom tab (personal app).

Can I do it by a POST?

I try to return to the user one Adaptive Card with the Action.OpenUrl suggested action but it only opens the url:

```
 {
        type: "AdaptiveCard",
            body: [
                {
                    type: "ColumnSet",
                    columns: [
                        {
                            type: "Column",
                            width: "auto",
                            items: [
                                {
                                    type: "TextBlock",
                                    size: "Large",
                                    text: title
                                },
                                {
                                    type: "TextBlock",
                                    text: details1
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            type: "Column",
                            width: "auto",
                            items: [
                                {
                                    type: "Image",
                                    url: '',
                                    size: "Large",
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            actions: [
                {
                    "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                    "title": "Details",
                    "card": {
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "body": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "text": details2,
                                "wrap": true
                            },
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                    "title": "Open",
                    "url": details3
                }
            ],
            $schema: "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            version: "1.0"
  }
```

How can I solve it?
I can call a callback function?
I can make a POST call with necessary data?
If anyone knows a method, please explain to me how can I do.
Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the access token at the moment? Via bot SSO? Have you looked into Tab SSO? Are you even using the token in the bot (or are you just wanting it to pass to the Tab)? Is it used in the message extension?

Comment: The access Token is stored into external table storage and it is get by login that can be make by message extension type auth and by custom login tab. Is it possible pass it by post from server (node  / message extension) to the client (personal app)? Because my tm wan't the user data pass throught get protocol. The trouble is that: when user click into preview card  it must go to the detail page (client) of the clicked item. For get the detailed of the item, I must have the item id  and the access token or the aad and tid of the user, for get the accesstoken and then the data of the item.

Comment: you definitely should not pass the token via Get, and I'm not sure it's a good idea to pass via POST either, it can also be insecure. I'm not sure you should be storing the token -at all- though, let alone passing it around. Are you doing some kind of SSO in the message extension, in order to get the token in the first place? If so, you can implement SSO in the tab as well (see here for a sample https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-sso). The user will have already consented in the Message Extension, so the experience should be very seamless.

Comment: It saves your problem of passing it, and means you don't need to "store" the token at all.

Comment: storing the token or user credentials is not a good practice. You can implement tab SSO and get user details from the token as Hilton suggested.

Comment: The difference is tath my authentication flow is with an external service and for make it I've already implement oath2 flow code, it doesn't support SSO or graph api. It can be do only with personal user and password into opened popUp tath user open when click on a login button inside a react tab or when search from messaging extension tath return an auth type because user it's not yet logged.

Comment: Messaging extension and tab are same part of entire project but are two different solution, and my trouble is how can i pass the returned access token from client side (react tab or personal app) to my node js service ( messaging extesion). For tath I decide to store into a table storage the received accessToken, for get it then from service. Can I change the flow?

Comment: @Leonardo : I have discussed this with my team in detail, and I have received a response stating that there is no such standard practice to route the token from ME to Tab. They suggested approach of table storage(using timestamp, tenant id, userid, accesstoken) which you have already implemented to be correct one but since, there is no secured way of passing token, it must be avoided.

Comment: OK, I'll try other solutions, thanks for everything.